# Selection rules are not firing immediately in Quote Line Editor in Salesforce CPQ

Tags: cpq

I am doing following trailhead. I created 2 product rules to disable and enable Electrical installation based on selection of US POWER OUTLET. It says in the trailhead that I should see that Electrical Installation should be automatically enabled and checked when I select check box next to US POWER OUTLET. But I see that it is still disabled. I went ahead and clicked Save in Product configurator page. Electrical Installation Product got added in the Quote Line Editor. Hence Selection rule is running fine. However it is not happening immediately. I also checked package level settings. Couldn't find any relevant setting related to this. What am I missing here?

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/product-rules-in-salesforce-cpq/control-options-with-selection-rules?trail_id=cpq-admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I missed adding Apply Immediately checkbox for US OUTLET Product option in Home Automation bundle. I did that and it is working as expected.